# I created table and cannot update in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I created a table and try to perform a basic update, but the result is 0 . Here is the script:

```
Create Table Working_Table 
   (Tot_Rec decimal(18,3),
    Tot_Bad_Rec decimal(18,3),
    Field_DQ_Score decimal(18,3),
    Tab_Name nvarchar(50) NULL
   );

   update Working_Table 
   Set Tab_Name = 'y';
```

Result

### is " (0 row(s) affected)

Additionally, when I run the following the rules is 0. I would like to have a result in percentage value, but event in decimal it does not display. The table parameters are above. The values are (11-2)/11

```
(Select ([Tot_Rec]-[Tot_Bad_Rec])/[Tot_Rec]from [dbo].[Working_Table]
);
```

Thank you.

OK

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no values in your table you can't update a row.
What you're probably looking for is INSERT INTO ...

so maybe you could use

```
INSERT INTO Working_Table VALUES (0,0,0,'y')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Working_Table (Tab_Name) VALUES ('y');
```

---

Part 2
If you want to divide sth. then you should probably add the following constraint to your Tot_Rec column, to prevent errors caused by an attempt to divide by zero.

```
ALTER TABLE Working_Table ADD CONSTRAINT Tot_Rec_Not_0 CHECK (Tot_Rec <> 0)
```

If that doesn't suffice post the error shown.